# shiny app rmarkdown report problem for plot

Tags: shiny, r-markdown

I am developing shiny app which has plot+table and download report button. when report is downloaded, i can see table but can't see plot. Any suggestion are welcome. Thanks here some part of my codes.

app.R

```
...
output$roc_plot <- renderPlot({
    res <- analysis()
    generate_roc_plot(res)
  
  })
...
  # Add download handler
  output$download_report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("ROC_analysis_", Sys.Date(), ".html", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      # R Markdown template dosyasını geçici bir klasöre kopyalayın
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      
      # Rapor için parametreleri ayarlayın
      res <- analysis()
      roc_plot <- generate_roc_plot(res)
      roc_table <- generate_roc_table(res)
      params <- list(roc_plot = roc_plot, roc_table = roc_table)
      
      # R Markdown dosyasını işleyin ve parametreleri ile birlikte geçirin
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
```

report.Rmd

````
title: "ROC Analysis"
output: html_document
params:
  roc_plot: NA
  roc_table: NA
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
# The `params` object is available in the document.
params$roc_plot

params$roc_table

  
  })
````